# Should it be "concerned person" or "person concerned"?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, word-order

An office colleague wrote the following in an email:

> Kindly log a ticket for the same and assign it to the *concerned team*.

I wrote back the following:

> I believe it should be
>   "Kindly log a ticket for the same and assign it to the *team concerned*."

Which one is correct, and why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*The team concerned* is short for something like *the team that is concerned with it*. While *the concerned team* is also valid in that context, on its own I'd be more likely understand it as referring to a team of people that are feeling worried. So you're both correct, but I'd say your phrasing is generally preferable.

Comment: Usage is fluid, but it is probably more standard to refer to the user who reported the problem as a "concerned person" and the team responsible for rectifying the problem as the "team concerned".

Comment: @Stan: Yes, thanks for the clarification. I should have included that in my answer, but as you say, usage varies.

Comment: @bye does "concerned team" and "team concerned" actually make that difference? I want to get it assigned to the team "dealing" with it, which may not necessarily be "concerned" with it.

Answer (score 1):

> Kindly log a ticket for the same and assign it to the concerned team.

The sentence could be understood as referring to the worried (or troubled, or anxious) team. As *concerned team* is preceded by *assign it to*, most of the people would understand what you exactly meant.

> Kindly log a ticket for the same and assign it to the team concerned.

This sentence would be understood as if it was referring to "the team concerned in [handling such tickets]".

This is similar to the phrase "the organs concerned in digestion and in blood-making", where the part after *concerned* is explicit. In both the phrases, *be concerned in* means "have a specific connection with or responsibility for".

Comment: I wouldn't think the team in question is concerned with handling tickets. Rather, the team *needs* a ticket. The ticket issue *concerns* the team in the question. It's the other way round.